# Prove expression for center of mass of a curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, integration, geometry

> While reading a book, I have come across the following expression for the abscissa of the center of mass of a curve $y=y(x)$, $a\leq x\leq b$:
>   $$\frac{\int_a^bx\sqrt{1+y'^2}\ dx}{\int_a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2}\ dx}.$$

How can this expression be proven? I know that $\int_a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2}\ dx$ is the length of the curve, but I can't figure out how to go on from there. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general equation for the x-coordinate of the center of mass is 
$$x_{CM}=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{\Delta m} x\cdot\Delta m$$
where we have split the big mass $M$ in many little $\Delta m$. Assume the (linear) density of the line is constant. 
$$\rho=\frac{M}{L}=\frac{\Delta m}{\Delta l}$$
Here $\Delta l$ and $L$ are the lengths of respectively a small line piece and the entire line. Substituting $M$ and $\Delta m$ gives a sum dependent only on $\Delta l$ and $L$.
$$x_{CM}=\frac{1}{\rho L}\sum_{\Delta l} x\cdot\rho\Delta l=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{\Delta l} x\cdot\Delta l$$
If you know how to calculate the length of the line rewriting $\Delta l$ in terms of $\Delta x$ should be familiar:
$$\Delta l=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}=\Delta x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)^2}$$
Finally let $\Delta x$ become infinitesimally small; the sum over all $\Delta x$ becomes an integral.
$$x_{CM}=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{\Delta x} x\cdot\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)^2}\Delta x\rightarrow\frac{1}{L}\int x\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your curve has a mass density per unit length of the curve of $\lambda=dm/ds$, that thus the mass as a function of $s$ is $m(s)=\lambda s$, and that the total mass of your curve is $$M=\int_{m(a)}^{m(b)} dm=\int_{s(a)}^{s(b)} \lambda ds=\lambda{\int_a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2}\ dx}$$ Consequently, the x-coordinate of the center of mass is defined by $$\bar x= \frac {1}{M}\int_a^b x dm = \frac {1}{M}\int_a^b x \lambda ds=\frac{\int_a^bx\sqrt{1+y'^2}\ dx}{\int_a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2}\ dx}$$ which gives you the answer to your question.